# Why I can't unpack a .zip folder on GUI?

Tags: directory, zip

I download a .zip folder/file and I have two installed unpacking programmes (Archiver for .zip files, 7zip). But when I click on the unpacking here options it says An error occurred while loading the acrhívum. If I would like to choose what program unpacking it with, I can't choose the Archiver for .zip files or 7zip. What can I do in this situation to unpacking the .zip folder/file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an archive manager says it's received an error loading an archive, chances are the archive is corrupted. Try downloading it again.

To set the default application for a specific file type, right-click the file and select `Open With...`. Find the application you prefer in the list and make sure the check box saying `Always use this application` or something to that extent is checked. After that, the file should open with the desired program once you click `Open`.

Comment: Note though that the "change what opens the application" only works should the archive be intact - if it's corrupt or multipart you're kinda stuck needing to redownload / reobtain it.